# Neo4j - Readify - convert to interface property

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher

I have one object with one of the property which is collection of "InterfaceA".

The cypher query generated with Readify gives me expected result in neo4j browser tool. But C# code fails to desearlize the response since it fails to recognize to which object type the collection should be desearlized.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution for same.
One need to use convertor for same -

```
client.JsonConverters.Add(new CustomJsonConverter());
```